# Access Denied After ERPal Platform Install

Tags: distributions

I've successfully installed ERPal Plaform with a LAMP stack on a fresh install of Ubuntu 12.04 on a VPS, and it goes to the administrative console after install. It's fully functional until I log out. When I log out, I get an Access Denied message whenever I trying to go to the domain it is installed on. I tried to chmod 777 the document root, but that didn't have any effect. Any ideas how I can deal with this issue and get access to the home page?

Comment: Have you looked at the permissions page to see if anonymous users should have acccess? Your file permissions have nothing to do with Drupal access decisions.

Answer (score 0):

Currently ERPAL platform is in active development status, and you can use ERPAL platform in full power, like admin user only. As ERPAL platform is based on Drupal, you can configure permissions by yourself on admin pages.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been fixed in subsequent releases.